# Removing object from ArrayList in Java

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist, foreach

I have this, where everytime a Bullet reaches the position greater than my screen width, it has to be destroyed. When i try this, the game crashes.

"bullet" is my class which contains the i's as objects.

"bullets" is my arraylist, containg all of the objects.

EDIT: Trying with Iterator now, but still still crashes.

EDIT: Accepted answer helped me. Working now. Thanks!

```
public ArrayList<bullet> bullets = new ArrayList<bullet>();
public Iterator<bullet> it = bullets.iterator();

while (it.hasNext()) {
           bullet s = it.next();
           if(s.xPosition > screenWidth - 10) {
               it.remove();
           }
        }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Efficient equivalent for removing elements while iterating the Collection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/223918/efficient-equivalent-for-removing-elements-while-iterating-the-collection)

Comment: What do you mean by crash? Do you have NullPointerException? Can you be more explicit about the error you have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot remove elements from your List while iterating over it. you will get `ConcurrentModificationException` if you do it. 
 you should use an iterator and remove elements from the iterator.

```
Iterator<Bullet> itr = bullets.iterator();
while(itr.hasNext()) {
    if(itr.next().xPosition > screenWidth - 10) {
        itr.remove(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, that's cool and everything, but that didn't really help me alot, since i don't know how to make one of these.

Comment: @KevinJensenPetersen check out duplicate posted as a comment under your question .