# ArrayList iterator remove crash

Tags: java, android

I have array inside array, I a need find in second array some items and remove parent array, but when I'm trying remove array I had an error java.lang.IllegalStateException

```
 productsList = new ArrayList<>(mSortModels);
    for (ProductComponentsResponse component : filterData) {
        String componentId = component.getId();
        int componentState = component.getState();
        Iterator<ProductResponse> iterator = productsList.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            ProductResponse next = iterator.next();
            for (ProductComponentsResponse productComponentsResponse: next.getProductComponents()) {
                boolean containComponent = productComponentsResponse.getId().contains(componentId);
                if (componentState == ProductComponentsResponse.FilterState.NONE) {
                    continue;
                } else if (componentState == ProductComponentsResponse.FilterState.SELECTED) {
                    if (!containComponent) {
                        Log.d("component", String.valueOf(containComponent));
                        ***iterator.remove();*** - this error line
                    }
                } else if (componentState == ProductComponentsResponse.FilterState.UNSELECTED) {
                    if (containComponent) {
                        iterator.remove();

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: can you be more specific of the error? what is the state of your variables at that time? at which line do you get the error? ..

Comment: add this information to the question, not in a comment, please

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing object from ArrayList in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14813330/removing-object-from-arraylist-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

`Iterator.remove()` removed the parent, but you continue looping over the children. Sometimes maybe calling `remove()` on the same parent again. That could cause your crash.

To solve this: put a `break;` after both `iterator.remove()`s to break out of the inner for loop when you have  removed its parent. This way you won't continue looping the children of a removed parent.

Answer (score 0):

I have simplified your code snippet to make it more easy to follow:

```
ProductResponse next = iterator.next();
for (ProductComponentsResponse productComponentsResponse: next.getProductComponents()) {
    if (condition1) {
        continue;
    } else if (condition2) {
        iterator.remove();
    } else if (condition3) {
        iterator.remove();
    }
}
```

You are calling `iterator.next()` once but then you get in a `for` loop where if `condition2` or `condition3` is satisfied you remove the iterator. Then you continue looping and if `condition2` or `condition3` is satisfied you again remove the same iterator which was removed in a previous step of the `for` loop. So you get the `IllegalStateException`. You should do the `iterator.remove()` call only once, try placing a `break;` after each `else if` block.

```
ProductResponse next = iterator.next();
for (ProductComponentsResponse productComponentsResponse: next.getProductComponents()) {
    if (condition1) {
        continue;
    } else if (condition2) {
        iterator.remove();
        break;
    } else if (condition3) {
        iterator.remove();
        break;
    }
}
```